# 'my_app' module not found error Django - Executing a script which uses my_app models

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a `python` script that uses my application models, but I get an error.

My directory structure:

```
my_app
   -venv   (My virtual environment)
   -manage.py
   -my_web_app
      -Scripts
         -CreateDBTAFs.py   (This is the script i'm trying to execute)
```

And here, my script imports (in `CreateDBTAFs.py`):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/my_app/')
import os, sys
PWD = os.getenv('PWD')
os.chdir(PWD)
sys.path.insert(0, os.getenv('PWD'))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings.py")
import django
django.setup()

#import standalone
#standalone.run('my_app.settings')

from my_web_app.models import MyModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from nltk import word_tokenize
import my_web_app.models
import os
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_web_app/Scripts/CreateDBTAFs.py", line 2, in <module>
    standalone.run('taf_analytics.settings')
  File "/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/standalone.py", line 27, in run
    django.setup()
  File "/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'
```

Comment: did you create your project using : "django-admin startproject yourproject". from the given structure  It seems you did not

Comment: Do you have a file called `local_settings.py` ?

Comment: Have you looked into using a [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead of a standalone script?